# Can IFTTT automate or control an iPhone?

Tags: bluetooth, automation, iphone

I am looking into [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) as a alternative to [Tasker](https://alternativeto.net/software/tasker/?platform=iphone) or [Llama](https://alternativeto.net/software/llama/?platform=iphone) context-aware task automation.

Especially I am looking for controlling the various radio devices on an iPhone, like Bluetooth, NFC, WiFi or mobile data.

However, I am stuck at the IFTTT home page.

**IFTTT seems to be able to control many things that have an API for it, but what about local stuff like the device settings (on an iPhone)? How to find out?**

*Note 1: I do not actually own an iPhone. I only want to buy if there is an automated way to control radio devices*

*Note 2: Feel free to move this question to another site, if more suitable.*

Comment: The Workflow app is better suited for manipulating stuff directly on the phone. But there isn't an URL based API to control radio devices so you are out of luck anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## IFTTT

IFTTT requires iOS devices that offer integration or an API that can be accessed. General remote access to iOS is not permitted.

The [IFTTT iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ifttt/id660944635?mt=8) makes the following claim for iOS support:

> Over 500 apps work with IFTTT including Twitter, Telegram, Google Drive, Twitch, Weather Underground, Instagram, Gmail, and devices like Google Home, Amazon Alexa, Nest, Philips Hue, and your iPhone. The IFTTT app also integrates with the Health app, so you can easily track and maintain your habits.

Supporting apps could work with background push notifications and updates to perform actions. This would work over any user permitted data connection.

Search for [`IFTTT iOS app`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=IFTTT+iOS+app) to find iOS apps claiming support and related recipes, such as:

- [How to Set Up and Use IFTTT on Your iPhone](https://www.scrubly.com/blog/how-to-iphone/how-to-set-up-and-use-ifttt-on-your-iphone/)
- [9 essential IFTTT recipes for iOS users](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/essential-ifttt-recipes-for-ios-users/)

## Mobile Device Management

Automation of an iOS is limited compared to macOS. The best way to remotely manage settings on an iPhone is via a [Mobile Device Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/1-Introduction/Introduction.html) (MDM) tool.